# How to edit colors.xml on specific way in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, colors

Is there any possibility to do something like this in colors.xml
For example:

```
//define a constants with color name and color value
red = #ea1111
// and than use it like this
<color name="colorPrimary">red</color>
```

My question is: Could I declare something like global variable in xml, and call that variable wherever I wish in xml file?

Comment: `<color name="satanic">#666</color>` `<color name="colorPrimary">@color/satanic</color>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you declare it like this in colors:

```
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```